# MacOS Automator shell script command not found, but works fine in Terminal

Tags: applescript, zsh, automator, zshrc

I'm trying to automate a command from a package installed globally with npm, "idasen-control" (controlling an Ikea desk over Bluetooth). In MacOS Automator (zsh shell) I'm getting a "command not found" when using shell script, but if I use it directly in Terminal it works fine. Also if I use AppleScript inside Automator and call Terminal it also works. But that means that a Terminal window gets open every time I call the command which is what I want to avoid.

This is a functioning workaround:

```
tell application "Terminal" to do script "idasen-control --move-to 14"
delay 0.8
tell application "Terminal" to close windows
```

This is what I've found when I type "echo $PATH" in Terminal:

```
/Users/MYUSERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

and this is what I get when I type it inside Automator in a "Run Shell Script":

```
  /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I added the alias in my .zshrc file (first line was there already):

```
source ~/.bash_profile
alias idasen-control='/Users/MYUSERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/idasen-control'
```

and I run "source ~/.zshrc" but this didn't help. I'm guessing it's just a PATH issue, so what should I add to my .zshrc file to fix this?

Comment: The default `PATH` passed to a `do shell script` _command_ or a **Run Shell Script** _action_ is `"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"` and anything called that is not within that path, the _fully qualified pathname_ needs to be used or include a `PATH` _statement_ as a _compound command_, i.e. the actual `PATH=$PATH`, where `$PATH` is the actual `PATH` followed by a `;` and the additional _commands_ in a `do shell script` _command_, or as the first statement in the **Run Shell Script** _action_.

Comment: @user3439894 It was a bit difficult to understand from your answer, but this is what works, defining the Path and then using it **every time** I call the command:
`set setPath to "PATH=~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin;
do shell script setPath & "idasen-control -m 14"`

I also choose AppleScript instead of normal **Run Shell Script** because of flexibility (if and for loops, variables, dialogs etc)

Comment: I have another related problem now - when trying to run these two commands at the same time the Script Editor **keeps running indefinitely**. In the Terminal the commands look like this: `"idasen-control --server & blueutil --disconnect [address]`, and in editor I write this: `do shell script setPath & "idasen-control --server; blueutil --disconnect [address]"`. I also tried `do shell script setPath & "idasen-control --server & blueutil --disconnect [address]"` but it also runs indefinitely. Is it waiting for some kind of response?

Comment: @nahero On 'path': It's not that you must explicitly set your path with each command. Because the path to 'idasen-control' is not known to 'do shell script', you must explicitly include the _fully qualified pathname_ with the 'idasen-control' command. While you could likely guess its path, type 'which idasen-control' in the terminal and it will return the path. Put that in your script like this: `do shell script "/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/idasen-control etc…."` This applies to any command that isn't located in one of the paths which @user3439894 listed.

Comment: @nahero On running indefinitely: The applescript interprets your command and sends that to the shell which adds its own interpretation. So… What is 'blueutil'? What is '[address]'? If the former is an applescript variable, then you need to move it outside the quotes like so: `"/path/idasen-control --server " & blueutil & " --disconnect…."` Note the added spaces inside the quotes. And if the latter is an address, it probably requires `'quoted form of [address]'`. I can't fit the full URL here but search for Apple's 'Technical Note TN2065' for further details.

Comment: @Mockman `blueutil` is a bluetooth utility also installed via npm, but I discovered it has a different path than `idasen-control`. Now when I run `blueutil` separately it works because I set the proper path. But, the problem of running indefinitely persists because of `idasen-control --server` command which starts the server that runs for as long as needed. There is nothing in the script I can do after this command, it just keeps running indefinitely. Only if I run `idasen-control --stop-server` via terminal it shows an error that server stopped and also stops the script.

Comment: I got it, adding `>/dev/null 2>&1 &` after the `idasen-control --server` fixed it for me. The full line is split like this: `do shell script setPath & "idasen-control --server >/dev/null 2>&1 &  " & bluePath & "blueutil --disconnect " & deskAddress`, where setPath and bluePath are respective paths, and deskAddress is a MAC address and doesn't need to be `quoted form of`

Comment: Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to use AppleScript to run a script in Automator. Instead, you can create an Application or Workflow.

### How to create an Applicaton which runs a script

1. Open Automator
2. Click **New**
3. Select **Application**
4. Search for **Run Shell Script**
5. Drag and Drop it to the area which reads *Drag actions or files to build your workflow*
6. Update your shell script to read the following:

```bash
export PATH=/Users/MYUSERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
idasen-control --move-to 14
```

7. Save the application

[image: An application created in Automator. The application calls the Run Shell Script action. It contains the same code as shared above in step 6.]

### How to automatically load this Application on start-up

1. Go to your Mac’s **System Preferences**
2. Go to **Users & Groups**
3. Select **your user**
4. Select the **Login Items** tab
5. Click the **+ icon** towards the bottom of the window
6. Select the application you just created